# How not to change an object in a method

Tags: java

I have a lab about complex numbers. I have to have

- two instance variables, a and b, which represent variables in a+bi.
- two constructors, one with the two instance variables and a default constructor.
- toString method that returns the complex number
- double modulus which returns (a*a+b*b)^(1/2).
- int quadrant that returns the quadrant (1-4) for a complex number or a 0 if the number is located on one of the axis (So if a>0, b>0, it's in the first quadrant).
- ComplexNumber conjugate that makes and returns the conjugate.
  (which basically is just returning the complex number with (-b) instead of b.
- ComplexNumber add (ComplexNumber other) that builds and returns sum of this number and the other number
- ComplexNumber subtract (ComplexNumber other) that builds and returns difference of this number and the other number.
- ComplexNumber multiply (ComplexNumber other) that builds and returns product of this number and another number.

Here is my code:

```
public class ComplexNumber {
       private int a;
       private int b;

       public ComplexNumber(int c, int d){
           a=c;
           b=d;
       }

       public ComplexNumber(){
           a=0;
           b=1;
       }

       public int getA(){
           return a;
       }

       public int getB(){
           return b;
       }

       public void setA( int newA){
           a=newA;
       }

       public void setB( int newB){
           b=newB;
       }

       public String toString(){
           if (a!=0&&b!=0){
                return a+"+("+b+")*i";
           }
           else if (b!=0&&a==0){
                return "("+b+")*i";
           }
           else if(a!=0&&b==0){
                return a+"";
           }
           else 
                return "0";
       }

       public double modulus(){
           return Math.sqrt((a*a+b*b));
       }

       public int quadrant(){
           if(a>0&&b>0){
               return 1;
           }
           else if (a>0&&b<0){
               return 4;
           }
           else if (a<0&&b>0){
               return 2;
           }
           else if (a<0&&b<0){
               return 3;
           }
           else 
               return 0;
       }

       ComplexNumber conjugate(){
           b=-b;
           return new ComplexNumber (a,b);
       }

       ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber other){
           return new ComplexNumber(this.a+other.a,this.b+other.b);
       }

       ComplexNumber subtract(ComplexNumber other){
           a=Math.abs(this.a-other.a);
           b=Math.abs(this.b-other.b);
           return new ComplexNumber(a,b);
       }

       ComplexNumber multiply(ComplexNumber other){
           a=(this.a)*(other.a)+(this.b)*(other.b);
           b=(this.a)*(other.b)+(this.b)*(other.a);
           return new ComplexNumber(a,b);
       }
}
```

And the tester is

```
      public class ComplexNumber_Tester   {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
         //checking toString()
       ComplexNumber a1= new ComplexNumber();
       System.out.println(a1);
       ComplexNumber a2= new ComplexNumber(0,0);
       System.out.println(a2);
       ComplexNumber a3= new ComplexNumber(4,0);
      System.out.println(a3);
       ComplexNumber a4= new ComplexNumber(-4,-7);
       System.out.println(a4);
       ComplexNumber a5= new ComplexNumber(8,-27);
       System.out.println(a5);
       ComplexNumber a6= new ComplexNumber(5,4);
       System.out.println(a6);

  // checking modulus()
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("abs value of ("+a5+") = "+ a5.modulus());
  System.out.println("abs value of ("+a1+") = "+ a1.modulus());
  System.out.println("abs value of ("+a3+") = "+ a3.modulus());
   // checking conjugate()
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("conjugate of ("+a5+") = "+ a5.conjugate());
  System.out.println("conjugate of ("+a1+") = "+ a1.conjugate()); 
  System.out.println("conjugate of ("+a3+") = "+ a3.conjugate());
  // checking add()
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("add ("+a5+")and ("+a4+"):     "+ a5.add(a4)); 
  System.out.println("add ("+a4+")and ("+a5+"):     "+ a4.add(a5)); 
  System.out.println("add ("+a1+")and ("+a5+"):     "+ a5.add(a1)); 
// checking subtract()
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("subtract ("+a5+")and ("+a4+"):     "+ a5.subtract(a4)); 
  System.out.println("subtract ("+a4+")and ("+a5+"):     "+ a4.subtract(a5)); 
  System.out.println("subtract ("+a1+")and ("+a5+"):     "+ a1.subtract(a5)); 
  // checking multiply()
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("multiply ("+a5+")and ("+a4+"):     "+ a5.multiply(a4)); 
  System.out.println("multiply ("+a4+")and ("+a5+"):     "+ a4.multiply(a5)); 
  System.out.println("multiply ("+a1+")and ("+a5+"):     "+ a1.multiply(a5));
  System.out.println("multiply ("+a3+")and ("+a6+"):     "+ a3.multiply(a6));
  System.out.println("multiply ("+a5+")and ("+a2+"):     "+ a5.multiply(a2)); 
    // checking quadrant()
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println(a5+"  is in quadrant "+a5.quadrant()); 
       System.out.println(a3+"  is in quadrant "+a3.quadrant()); 
       System.out.println(a4+"  is in quadrant "+a4.quadrant()); 
       System.out.println(a6+"  is in quadrant "+a6.quadrant()); 
       System.out.println(new ComplexNumber(-6, 7)+"  is in quadrant "+ new ComplexNumber(-6, 7).quadrant());    
  }
  }
 /*
    1*i
 0
 4
 -4-7*i
 8-27*i
 5+4*i

  abs value of (8-27*i) = 28.160255680657446
  abs value of (1*i) = 1.0
  abs value of (4) = 4.0

  conjugate of (8-27*i) = 8+27*i
  conjugate of (1*i) = -1*i
  conjugate of (4) = 4

  add (8-27*i)and (-4-7*i):     4-34*i
  add (-4-7*i)and (8-27*i):     4-34*i
  add (1*i)and (8-27*i):     8-26*i

subtract (8-27*i)and (-4-7*i):     12-20*i
subtract (-4-7*i)and (8-27*i):     -12+20*i
subtract (1*i)and (8-27*i):     -8+28*i

multiply (8-27*i)and (-4-7*i):     -221+52*i
multiply (-4-7*i)and (8-27*i):     -221+52*i
multiply (1*i)and (8-27*i):     27+8*i
multiply (4)and (5+4*i):     20+16*i
 multiply (8-27*i)and (0):     0

 8-27*i  is in quadrant 4
   4  is in quadrant 0
   -4-7*i  is in quadrant 3
    5+4*i  is in quadrant 1
    -6+7*i  is in quadrant 2

*/
```

The thing is, I get

```
 (1)*i
  0
  4
 -4+(-7)*i
  8+(-27)*i
  5+(4)*i

abs value of (8+(-27)*i) = 28.160255680657446
abs value of ((1)*i) = 1.0
abs value of (4) = 4.0

conjugate of (8+(-27)*i) = 8+(27)*i
conjugate of ((1)*i) = (-1)*i
 conjugate of (4) = 4

add (8+(27)*i)and (-4+(-7)*i):     4+(20)*i
add (-4+(-7)*i)and (8+(27)*i):     4+(20)*i
add ((-1)*i)and (8+(27)*i):     8+(26)*i

subtract (8+(27)*i)and (-4+(-7)*i):     12+(34)*i
subtract (-4+(-7)*i)and (12+(34)*i):     16+(41)*i
subtract ((-1)*i)and (12+(34)*i):     12+(35)*i

multiply (12+(34)*i)and (16+(41)*i):     1586+(65570)*i
multiply (16+(41)*i)and (1586+(65570)*i):     2713746+(1846731110)*i
multiply (12+(35)*i)and (1586+(65570)*i):     2313982+(1403999890)*i
multiply (4)and (5+(4)*i):     20+(80)*i
multiply (1586+(65570)*i)and (0):     0

 0  is in quadrant 0
 20+(80)*i  is in quadrant 1
 2713746+(1846731110)*i  is in quadrant 1
 5+(4)*i  is in quadrant 1
 -6+(7)*i  is in quadrant 2
```

For the add method, I am supposed to use 8-27i not the conjugate.

I know this happens because the add method, subtract method, and the multiply method change the object, so the method takes whatever the object is changed into.

Could you help me fix the methods so that it won't change the object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A fix in explanation. The reason it takes 8+27i is probably because of the conjugate method, not the add method. How do I fix the conjugate method so that the add method won't take the changed object but take the original one?

Comment: Ok, but it looks like your problem is that you're changing `a` and `b` in those methods instead of declaring local variables. You can do `int newA; int newB;` inside a method and use those for your intermediate calculations.

Comment: But if I return return new ComplexNumber (a,NewB);

Comment: It still changes the object

Comment: so the conjugation of a+bi still becomes the new object in the method

Comment: Change to `private final int a; private final int b;` and the compiler shows the problem points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your methods are changing your objects values is because they are performing operations **directly** on the class variable.

To avoid this you could declare local variables within each method for the operations to be performed on.

Here is an example of how you could do that with the add method:

```
public class ComplexNumber {
    private int a;
    private int b;

public ComplexNumber(int x, int y) {
    a = x;
    b = y;
}

public ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber other) {
    int tempA = a + other.a;
    int tempB = b + other.b;

    return new ComplexNumber(tempA, tempB);
}
```

---

P.S. At the time I am writing this answer your code is **very** hard to read, here is a good place to read about accepted practices for formatting java code, following these guidelines helps to keep your code easier to understand.

https://github.com/twitter/commons/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/common/styleguide.md#formatting

Comment: Also it would be preferred to declare a and b as finals